# Writing to binary file

Tags: c, input, binary, output

Writing a program that reads data from a text file and outputs it to a binary file. I am pretty sure i am reading the file correctly because when I print the information it does come out correctly. However, the writing to the binary file is incorrect. Each line of the text file reads:

> firstname lastname id gpa

Where the first and last name are strings of at most 255 characters, the id is an unsigned 4 byte integer, and the gpa is a 4 byte floating point number. I got it to read from the file and print the correct info, but there is something wrong with the output file. It comes out as almost 1.5 KB for a text file that was only 61 bytes. What is wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int textToBinary()
{
    FILE * textfile = fopen("t2.txt", "r"); //Open and read text file
    FILE * binfile = fopen("t2tobin.bin", "wb"); //Open writable bin file

    unsigned char firstName[256];
    unsigned char lastName[256];
    unsigned int id;
    float gpa;
    char nLine[]= "\n";
    char space[]= " ";

    if(NULL == textfile) //alerts and exits if binfile is not found
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file\n");
        fflush(stderr);
        exit(1);
    }


    //implement a loop to continue until the end of the file
    while(fscanf(textfile, "%s %s %d %f", firstName, lastName, &id, &gpa)!= EOF){
        //read one line of the text file
        printf("%s %s %d %.1f\n", firstName, lastName, id, gpa); //print line information ((test))
        //Writing information to binary file
        fwrite(firstName, sizeof(firstName), 1, binfile);//first name
        fwrite(space, sizeof(space), 1, binfile);//space
        fwrite(lastName, sizeof(lastName), 1, binfile);//last name
        fwrite(space, sizeof(space), 1, binfile);//space
        fwrite(&id, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, binfile);//ID
        fwrite(space, sizeof(space), 1, binfile);//space
        fwrite(&gpa, 4, 1, binfile);//gpa

        fwrite(nLine, sizeof(nLine), 1, binfile);//new line
    }

    fclose(binfile);
    fclose(textfile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's expected as each write of a string uses 256 bytes. Write 6 of them you get 1,5Kb ! aside: `fwrite(&gpa, 4, 1, binfile)` => `fwrite(&gpa, sizeof(float), 1, binfile)`

Comment: 1. Why are you not checking the return values from `fopen` - i.e. the binabry one. 2. Please format the code to make it readable

Comment: Use `strlen` instead of `sizeof` when writing to the file with `fwrite`.

Comment: You do not normally need newlines in a binary file; newlines are for us humans, and binary files are for other programs.

Comment: Using `strlen()` to `fwrite()` a string will be difficult to read back by `fread()`. The best way could be to record the value of `strlen()` before writing the string.

Comment: You are right in writing `sizeof(each_field)` but... Why do you asume the size of `gpa` is going to be `4` and don't use also `sizeof gpa` ????  By the way, if all fields are fixed size, why do you write the space separators and the new line?  I'm afraid you are mixing concepts.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that each time you write a string in output file you write exactly 256 bytes, because `sizeof(firstName)` equals 256 (see your declaration, 1 byte per character * 256).

Correct solution is to use `strlen` function (length of string) instead of `sizeof` when you write strings. But strings in C must end with `\0` character. When you read strings, your array of characters (firstName, lastName) gets filled with string and `\0` character at the end by default. So you just need to output string with this one byte at the end, that's why the actual amount of bytes you write for one string is `sizeof(string)+1`:

```
...
fwrite(firstName, strlen(firstName)+1, 1, binfile);//first name
fwrite(space, sizeof(space), 1, binfile);//space
fwrite(lastName, strlen(lastName)+1, 1, binfile);//last name
fwrite(space, sizeof(space), 1, binfile);//space
fwrite(&id, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, binfile);//ID
fwrite(space, sizeof(space), 1, binfile);//space
fwrite(&gpa, 4, 1, binfile);//gpa
...
```